# How to make this code in faster time complexity

Tags: python, time-complexity

I need to make a code that takes in list with tuples with two numbers such as [ (1, 2), (5, 8), (1, 3), (1, 1), (3, 6) ]. First number of tuple is day of the start of event and second number is the day it ends. This code should return biggest number of events going on at the same time and time complexity should be O(n). What i have problem with, is time complexity. This is the least time complex code i could write:

```
def divide_to_groups(calendar):
    if len(calendar) == 0:
        return 0

    def group_num(j, groups):    # takes index of group and list groups, returns last number of last tuple
        if isinstance(groups[j][-1], int):
            return groups[j][-1]
        else:
            return groups[j][-1][1]

    calendar = list(sorted(calendar))
    groups = [[calendar[0]]]

    for i in range(1, len(calendar)):

        for j in range(len(groups)):

            if group_num(j, groups) < calendar[i][0]:   # if previous group has time when current event begins
                groups[j].append(calendar[i])

                break
            elif j+1 == len(groups):
                groups.append([calendar[i]])

    return len(groups)

# Tests
def test_default():
    calendars = [
        [ ],
        [ (1, 2), (3, 3), (500, 800), (50, 56) ],
        [ (1, 2), (5, 8), (1, 3), (1, 1), (3, 6) ],
        [ (1, 1), (1, 50), (25, 75), (60, 100), (2, 3) ]
    ]

    answers = [ 0, 1, 3, 2 ]

    for i in range(len(calendars)):
        result = divide_to_groups(calendars[i])
        if result == answers[i]:
            print("[", i, "] OK.", sep="")
        else:
            print("[", i, "] Not OK. Expected ", answers[i], " but got ", result, ".", sep="")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    test_default()
```

Comment: What does `n` in `O(n)` stand for?

Comment: @dedObed it stands for how many actions your code will make if your input is n. Here is a link so you can read on it: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/understanding-time-complexity-simple-examples/

Comment: I (think that I) understand the big `O` notation quite well. My question is, what exactly does the `n` represent. Number of what, events? Or the total timespan covered?

Comment: It stands for number of events

Answer (score 0):

If N is your number of events.

In linear time O(N), you can probably fill out your ranges in a calendar-matrix with ones (or an X mark) where the columns would be days and sum each columns to see how many events there is on day D.

```
           1 2 .... 31
event1     x x x .....
event2       x x x ...
event3       x x .....
...
-----------------------
SUM        1 4 5 .....
```

And then calculate the maximal index `i` where `SUM(D=i)` is maximal.

You can even write a `sums(d)` list directly without having to store in an intermediate matrix, just using your range structures.

Another problem to consider would be encoding the day of the year in the column. Date libraries usually give you which day of the year (1 <= d <= 366) your date is.

Good luck.